# function prototypes in main or before main in C

Tags: c

Should the function prototype in C be in main or before main. I was taught before main, but my friends class book shows it in main. Which is the correct way?

His book shows it:

```
int main()
{
    void numberTable();

    numberTable();
}

void numberTable()
{
    int num;
    ...rest of the code...
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both are correct.
If you add the function declaration inside main, its scope is inside the main `{` `}`.
If you add it outside main, its scope is the entire source file.

Comment: is it better to put it before main? Just wondering because my teacher required all functions to be declared before main and I am wondering if that is necessary

Comment: I'd say it's better style to put prototypes at file scope, outside any function body.  You *can* have a prototype inside a function, or even inside a block, but that restricts the visibility of the prototype to that block, which is an odd thing to do.  For larger programs with multiple source files, most function prototypes are going to be in header files.

Comment: Exactly!  Not *wrong*, just rather odd. This answer + Keiths comment = GREAT answer.

Comment: K&R has example that declare functions inside of other functions.  Which is not to say it's a good reference on *STYLE*, but if it's in K&R, it's at least legal C.

Answer (score 3):

**It can be both way**. But If you declare outside main, then you can access everywhere in the code, in other case,its scope is within main.

Answer (score 2):

The reason to define the function before main is to avoid the function declaration that would be necessary if you define the function after main. It is common for C modules to be coded in this style, that is: functions defined in dependency order, in order to avoid the need for declarations of functions that are local in scope (we should be careful how we use the word scope here - scope is not enforced by the C linker).

Answer (score 1):

Either way can be made to work.  Declarations outside `main()` (or, more generally, outside any function) typically leads to less repetition.

When you declare the function inside `main()`, that declaration only applies in `main()`.  If some other function (e.g. `function_1()`) also calls the relevant function (e.g. `numberTable()`) and appears before the other function is defined, then you have to declare `numberTable()` inside `function_1()` as well (violating DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself, and also SPOT: Single Point of Truth).  If, on the other hand, the declaration of `numberTable()` was outside any function and before any function in the file, then all functions can use the one declaration.

If you have multiple source files involved, then the rules become simpler.  All functions callable from other files should be declared in a header (`header.h`).  That header should be included in every file that references any of the functions declared in header, and also in each of the files that defines each of the functions that is declared in the header.  The header should be included outside of any function in the files where it is used.  (The C standard requires this for the standard headers.)  This ensures that all the code has a consistent view of declaration of each function.  Eventually, you will get to big enough programs that there may even be multiple headers.  The same basic rules apply - declare functions in headers; include the headers (outside of any function) where the functions are used and defined.  (See also [What are `extern` variables in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c).)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct; however, it's not a good style in reality. 
A common good practice: put all those functions declaration and definition in other headers and source files: `header.h` + `header.c`